# SELECT command in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I was wondering if there is a way to do something like selecting all without ... some columns here

something like SELECT */column1,column2   , is there a way to do this ?
I just need to output something like

column1 , column2 ( from another table ) , here all other columns without column1 ( or something to make the select skip the first few columns)

EDIT:
The thing is that i need this to be dynamic  , so i cant just select what i don't know. I never know how many columns there will be , i just know the 1st and the 2nd column

EDIT: here is a picture http://oi44.tinypic.com/xgdyiq.jpg
I don't need the second id column , just the last column like i have pointed.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, so select all but certain fields. You have two options.

One is a little slow.. Copy the table, drop the fields you don't want, then SELECT *
The other is to build the field list from a subquery to information_schema or something, then remove occurrences of 'field_i_dont_want' in that list.

```
SELECT ( SELECT THE TABLES YOU WANT AND CONCAT INTO ONE STRING ) FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Start building custom views, which are geared aorund saving developers time and encapsulating them from the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to combine records from multiple tables, you need to find a way to relate them together. Primary Keys, Foreign Keys, or anything common among this.

I will try to explain this with a sql similar to your problem.

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.name, table1.column3, table1.column4 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 On table2.commmonfield = table1.commonfield
```

Comment: I do have primary and foreign keys , the thing is , all i want to do is : 

REPLACE the Foreign key(in the main table) with with what he was pointing(in the 2nd table). Not just to have the two tables in one.

Comment: @Jordashiro, Thats great, now update your question with your schema. I will provide a working solution right away ;)

Comment: By Foreign key i was talking about the column with this foreign key being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 'n' columns in your table as in Col1,Col2,Col3....Coln you can select whatever columns you want to select from the table.

```
SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You either select all columns (*) or especify the columns you want one by one. There is no way to select 'all but some'.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL language lets you either select a wildcard set of columns or enumerated single columns from a singular table.  However you can join a secondary table and get a wildcard there.

```
SELECT
  a.col1,
  b.*
FROM
  table_a as a
JOIN table_b as b ON (a.col5 = b.col_1)
```